# Fast file parsing C++

Tags: c++, file, parsing, stream

I am currently doing a project where I have to read a couple of large files. I would like to ask about some of the best practices for optimizing file parsing in C++.

After reading some benchmarks ([example](http://lemire.me/blog/archives/2012/06/26/which-is-fastest-read-fread-ifstream-or-mmap/)) regarding fread, ifstream, etc. I have decided to use ifstream for this purpose (if you believe there is a better way, please point out any improvements). The way I used it so far was like this:

```
  std::ifstream input_file ("some_file.txt");
  input_file.seekg (0, input_file.end);
  int length = input_file.tellg();       // Get the size of the buffer 
  input_file.seekg (0, input_file.beg);

  std::vector<char> buffer (length);
  input_file.read(&buffer[0], length);
```

Then I would use stringstream to parse the file like this:

```
  std::stringstream parser;
  parser.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(&buffer[0], length);
```

and continue parsing with stringstream parser.

The questions which I have are as fallows:

1. Does the above code copy the buffer to stringstream or are they sharing the same buffer? (I am not quite shure what pubsetbuf does or how efficient it is)
2. Is there a better way to do this instead of using stringstream?
3. When we know the length of some irrelevant information, i.e. "irrelevant information, important information", and we wish to get the important information, we could do something like this:

   ```
   std::string container; 
   parser.seekg(irrelevant_size, parser.cur); // irrelevant_size is the size 
                                              // of irrelevant data
   std::getline(parser, container);
   ```
4. How efficient is this compared to doing

   `parser.get(temp_char_array, irrelevant_size + 1);`

   to collect all the irrelevant data?

Comment: Get rid of the seeks and the tell and use `fstat()` to get the file size, not that you should really need it. You're better off reading a byte at a time via a buffer than reading the entire file before you process any of it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Do you have any source for the last sentence, as I have read that it is faster to put the complete file into a buffer? The explanation for that was that it is slower to read from file on the disk than from RAM.

Comment: @hamzam If you want to read the whole file multiple times, it can be better to load everything in the RAM instead of reaidng multiple times from HDD. But 1: If you want to skip an irrelevant part, you don´t want the whole file. But 2: Depending on the file size, loading into the RAM is bad or impossible altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pubsetbuf` won´t make a copy. See following link for more details:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/streambuf/streambuf/pubsetbuf/

And seeking forward in a file is (much) faster than reading everything between. Strictly speeking it´s not required to be faster, but on all usual OS it´s pretty much constant time (not really, but not proportional to the seek length in any way). Maybe the difference isn´t that much if only some bytes are skipped, but it gets more important with bigger distances.

Depending on how important a little more speed is,
your OS has some faster (but OS-dependent) functions.
And if there is a better parsing way depends on your data.
You should ask this in separate questions.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. To complete all the questions, I would like to ask if there is a better way of parsing the file instead of what I do - reading the complete file, and then using stringstream?

Comment: @hamzam DId you even read? It depends on your content, and you should ask it in another question with more details.

Comment: I did read what you wrote, but I didn't pose my question correctly. What I aimed at was getting a comment on the method I am doing - independent of the OS and the data, or a general tip in efficient file parsing (i.e. if there is a way that beats what I did in every aspect, or if I should avoid stringstreams, etc...).

Comment: `if there is a way that beats what I did in every aspect` No (a perfect solution for everything is rare :)) `if I should avoid stringstreams` No again. Depending on the data they can be everything between "all you need" and "completely useless". They are not the fastest, but compared with the disk access time it won´t matter in most cases (and thinking about runtime/worktime ratio, "not the fastest" may be "best". Eg. 1min less runtime isn´t worth 1day more programming)